# VB error catching

Tags: excel, vba

My code is as below

```
 conDB.Execute strSQL, recordsAffected
         Sheet1.Cells(intStart, 5) = IIf(recordsAffected > 0, "Success", "Failure")
```

Intread of printing failure i want to print the error description. I tried

```
Sheet1.Cells(intStart, 5) = IIf(recordsAffected > 0, "Success", Err.Des)
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, 0 rows affected doesn't mean an error occurred, does it?

Answer (score 1):

The Err object has a value only after an error occurs. So try this

```
Sub MySub(strSQL as string)
   On error goto CATCH 
   conDB.Execute strSQL, recordsAffected
   Sheet1.Cells(intStart, 5) = IIf(recordsAffected > 0, "Success", "Hmm ?")
exit sub 
CATCH:
   Sheet1.Cells(intStart, 5) = Err.Description
   on error goto 0
end sub
```